# Java 7: ThreadLocalRandom generating the same random numbers

Tags: java, random, java-7

I'm trying out Java 7's  [ThreadLocalRandom](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) and see that it is generating exactly the same random numbers across multiple threads.

Here is my code, in which I create 5 threads and each thread prints out 5 random numbers:

```
//5 threads
for(int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++) {
    final Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.print(Thread.currentThread().getName()+":");

            //each thread prints 5 random numbers
            for(int j = 0 ; j < 5; j++) {
                final int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1,100);
                System.out.print(random + ",");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    };
    thread.start();
    thread.join();
}
```

Output:

```
Thread-0:1,93,45,75,29,
Thread-1:1,93,45,75,29,
Thread-2:1,93,45,75,29,
Thread-3:1,93,45,75,29,
Thread-4:1,93,45,75,29,
```

Why am I getting the same random numbers for each thread and for every execution of the program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Seems like there's an open bug regarding this issue. See [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7051516) and [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6955840)

Comment: The bug has been solved in the Update 2 of JDK7. Download here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-7u2-download-1377129.html

Answer (score 5):

googling for the "ThreadLocalRandom source" gave me http://www.assembla.com/code/scala-eclipse-toolchain/git/nodes/src/forkjoin/scala/concurrent/forkjoin/ThreadLocalRandom.java

long/short of it: it uses a `ThreadLocal<ThreadLocalRandom>` which calls the no-arg constructor for construction

that no-arg constructor is

```
/**
 * Constructor called only by localRandom.initialValue.
 * We rely on the fact that the superclass no-arg constructor
 * invokes setSeed exactly once to initialize.
 */
ThreadLocalRandom() {
    super();
}
```

the no-arg super in [Random](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Random.java.html) calls this(long) with a unique seed

HOWEVER that constructor does

```
public Random(long seed) {
    this.seed = new AtomicLong(initialScramble(seed));
}
```

i.e. not the expected behavior from documentation

and ThreadLocalRandom doesn't/can't use the private `seed`

Comment: That isn't the JDK source (notice the `eclipse` and `scala` hints in the URL).  The real JDK source is at http://hg.openjdk.java.net, and here's [`ThreadLocalRandom`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.java)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this because the threads are being created at roughly the same time and thus getting seeded the same value from the timer? I was under the impression that was how that worked, though I may be mistaken.

Comment: It's not the same time, there is a big time difference - each thread is created only after the previous thread was terminated.