# Order id placeorder Java interactive brokers

Tags: java, interactive-brokers, ibrokers

Currently each time I place an order with

```
order.m_action = "BUY";
order.m_totalQuantity = 1;
order.m_lmtPrice = 4.00;
order.m_orderType = "LMT";  
order.m_account = "U123123";
int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5564 + 1)                    
m_s.placeOrder(randomNum, c, order);
```

I am getting the error:

```
1041 103 Duplicate order id
```

Any ideas on generating a new id for new entry orders?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using Java SE 7, then there is a bug. Check this http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7051516 and this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139525/java-7-threadlocalrandom-generating-the-same-random-numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your orderId's shouldn't be random numbers.  They have to be increasing numbers all the time.  `last id used +1` is the best algorithm.  `Duplicate order id` can actually mean "not an increasing order Id".

Note that when the socket connection is started, IB returns the next valid id in the nextValidId callback, so you always know which number to start on.

Some people (me included) use number ranges for certain requests so that errors with an id can be associated with the request type.  eg. I use numbers < 1000 for `reqMktData` type requests. Once you call `placeOrder` with a number > 1000, IB will never let you use a lower number for orders.

You can actually reset the `orderId` sequence, but I've never done that and won't until I run out of `ints`.

Comment: I think I need to reset it because i tested an order at 1000000000

Comment: do I just do public void nextValidId(int orderId) {    m_s.placeOrder(orderId+1, c, order);}

Comment: You still have 1147483647 ints left ;).  To reset, go to configure->api and click `reset api order sequence` button.  But in truth you shouldn't need to ever look at the orderId, just assign it to a variable in `nextValidId` and always increment by one.