# Generating random words from text file but combination is always the sam

Tags: java, android-studio

I've managed to generate random words from text file and it works, but the only problem is that combination is always the same. It doesn't matter if I restart the game or not. The combination remains the same. Here's the code:

```
public void correct_button(View view) {
        String text = "";
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("words.txt");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            text = new String(buffer);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        String[] separated = text.split("\n");
        int size = separated.length;
        int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, size - 1);
        String randomWord = separated[randomNum];
    }
```

Comment: Have you seen this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139525/java-7-threadlocalrandom-generating-the-same-random-numbers ?

Comment: So basically all I have to do is to update jdk?

Comment: Simply replace `int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, size - 1);` with `int randomNum = (int) (Math.random() * size - 1);`